# Marionette + RequireJs - Issues with lazy loading

Tags: requirejs, marionette

I've been trying to practice dependency resolution for `Mariotte` modules using `Require.js`. Lately, I've tried to learn how to source files lazily, ie. loading relevant `.js` files only when needed and not at application startup. However this is proving to be a nightmare. The following code fragments is how I'm trying to do things right now.

```js
define(['app'], function(App) {
    App.module('Header', function(Header, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

        this.doSomething = function() { alert('Did something!'); }
        this.getSomething = function() { return 'Something'; }

    }
});
```

Suppose that `doSomething` needs `subdep` to be loaded before it can do its work. I can ensure that as follows: I can verify in ChromeDevtools that `subdep` is only loaded when `this.doSomething()` is called.

```js
this.doSomething = function() {
    require(['subdep'], _.bind(function() {
        alert(this.SubDep.showSomething());
    }, this));
}
```

From here on, I have a couple of issues / questions that I'm looking forward to have addressed.

1. I need to use `_.bind()` to retain the value of `this`. The `require(...)` also pollutes the code visually. Is there a way around that, by maybe customizing the `Marionette.Module.prototype`? Something like this would be ideal:

   ```js
   this.doSomething = function() { alert(this.SubDep.showSomething()); }
   myRequireHash: {
       'this.doSomething' : ['subdep'],
       'this.getSomething' : ['subdep', 'underscore']
   }
   ```
2. Suppose `this.getSomething` needs to return a value to the caller. The following does not work, obviously, since the `require` statement initiates asynchronous loading and returns immediately. How do I work around this? I need to load the dependency **when actually needed** and also be able to **return a value**.

   ```js
   this.getSomething = function() {
       require(['subapp'], _.bind(function() {
           return this.SubApp.getSomething();
       }, this));
   }
   ```
3. As an extension to point #2, suppose the caller needs to call `this.doSomething()` **AFTER** calling `this.getSomething()`. Since the `require` calls are asynchronous, can I somehow return a `promise` from `this.getSomething()` that could be used to ensure that the two functions will be called **in sequence**? If so, then how?

Asim

---

**Update**

Using Paul's ideas, here is how I've tackled my situation:

```js
function RequirePromise (pListDeps, oContext, fnFunc)
{
    return $.Deferred(function(oDef)
    {
        require(pListDeps, function()
        {
            var pArgs = [];
            if (fnFunc)
            {
                if (oContext) fnFunc = _.bind(fnFunc, oContext);
                pArgs.push(fnFunc.apply(fnFunc, arguments));
            }
            oDef.resolveWith(oContext, _.union(pArgs, arguments));
        });
    }).promise();
}
```

`pListDeps` is a list of dependencies to be loaded. `oContext` is the preferred default context for the promise functions to be in. `fnFunc` is an optional function that runs in the given function (without chaining to the `then` function). The return value from the function is available as the first parameter in `then`/`done`. The loaded dependencies are available as 2nd parameter onwards. I can use this as any of the following:

```js
RequirePromise(['app'], this).done(function(App) { console.log(arguments); }

RequirePromise(['app'], this, function(App) { console.log(App); return true; })
    .done(function(oRet, App) { console.log(arguments); }

RequirePromise(['app'], this)
    .then(function() { return RequirePromise(['subapp']); })
    .done(function() { console.log('Both app and subapp loaded!'); }
```

Thanks Paul =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do what you want without either providing callbacks or deferreds/promises for all the async methods.

JavaScript doesn't really have a `wait`/`waitUntil`/`waitFor` concept like other languages, where you can wait for an async task to finish. And indeed you mostly don't want to do this, as it would 'hang' the browser.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/36fMx/) is an example of what I mean.

The JS below assumes some knowledge of [jQuery Deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

#### The HTML:

```
<script>
require = {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3",
        "mymodule": "https://rawgithub.com/gitgrimbo/5689953/raw/9b44d7e5f504b2245331be3ed3fcbb7bf8635da6/gistfile1"
    }
};
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.8/require.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
```

#### JS (1):

`dfdRequire` is a function that calls `require()` but returns a jQuery promise object.

The callback for `require()` is an internal one, and the dependencies returned by `require()` are used to resolve the deferred.

Basically this converts from a callback-based system to a promise-based one.

```
function dfdRequire(deps) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        require(deps, function() {
            dfd.resolve.apply(dfd, arguments);
        });
    }).promise();
}
```

This could actually be reduced to:

```
function dfdRequire(deps) {
    return $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        require(deps, dfd.resolve.bind(dfd));
    }).promise();
}
```

#### JS (2):

Create the dummy app module that uses the above function.

The `getSomething()` method will use `dfdRequire()` to load the `"mymodule"` module, and then use the `then()` method to actually use the module.

The function passed to `then()` uses the `mymodule` value by uppercasing it, and returning this new value. This means that when the method returns, it actually will return the uppercased value.

```
define("app", ["jquery"], function($) {
    return {
        doSomething: function(value) {
            console.log("doSomething with " + value);
        },
        getSomething: function() {
            // Load the dependency as a promise, and return that promise to the caller,
            // so the caller can also await its resolution.
            return dfdRequire(["mymodule"]).then(function(mymodule) {
                console.log("Loaded mymodule. Value=" + mymodule);
                // return the module value as-is,
                // or optionally perform some transformation.
                return mymodule.toUpperCase();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

#### JS (3):

Pull in the app and use its methods.

`app.getSomething()` will return a promise. We use this promise in a chain (to demonstrate that promise calls can be chained). Firstly, the value is passed to `console.log()` which will print the value. Then we call `app.doSomething()`.

```
require(["jquery", "app"], function($, app) {
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
    $("button").first().click(function(evt) {
        console.log(evt);
        app.getSomething()
            .done(console.log.bind(console))
            .done(app.doSomething.bind(app));
    });
});
```

We use [`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as shorthand for what could also be written as.

```
        app.getSomething()
            .done(function(value) {
                console.log(value);
            })
            .done(function(value) {
                app.doSomething(value);
            });
```

Results in:

```
2.0.3
Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=88448339, more...}
Loaded mymodule. Value=my-library
MY-LIBRARY
doSomething with MY-LIBRARY
```

Comment: hi paul.. im pretty sure this should do the trick.. lemme test it and report back.. this is EXACTLY one of the things i needed to know.. thanks in advance.. =)

Comment: hi again =).. the code you posted works as advertised.. but im lost in it.. can you explain how exactly it works? also the `bind` calls are baffeling me..

Comment: wow.. thank you for opening up my mind to new possibilities.. this will surely come in handy.. this is awesome!!! =) accepted! =)